# MpAndroidChart graph displays on few y axis lines

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I have data for the year i.e data for each month. I am using Line Chart to display the data. I have made some customizations. Problem is it will display only alternative months Y axis line. I want to display all the y axis lines. Please refer screenshot. 1st image is what I am getting. I want it to be like the 2nd image. [image]

[image]

Comment: I think your values are null try checking that..

Comment: @madhuri please check the answer and let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I solved it by setting the [zoom](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/Modifying-the-Viewport) level for the chart. You can do the following

`lineChart.zoom(2,0,0,0);`

In my case scaling x twice solved the problem.

Make sure you enable the drag feature in chart by the `lineChart.setDragEnabled(true);` because scaling x can make your line chart go beyond the screen size

You can also do `lineChart.setScaleEnabled(false);`, if you don't wish to scale chart any further.

Comment: Yes it works. But it would need scroll effect. My requirement is it should fit to the screen and show all the Y axis lines.

Comment: @madhuriHR as of now its seems impossible as it shows only 5 X axis gridlines regardless the number of items on X axis. The only way possible is described above.

Answer (score 0):

You can try reducing the granularity of the xAxis
e.g

```
XAxis xAxis = mLineChart.getXAxis();
xAxis.setGranularity(0.5f);
```